# Can we use "id est" in lieu of "i.e." in academic writing?

Tags: word-usage, writing, latin

In an academic, format context, can we write *id est* instead of its abbreviated form (*i.e.*)?

Compare:

> ‘a walking boot which is synthetic, **id est** not leather’

with:

> ‘a walking boot which is synthetic, **i.e.** not leather’

Comment: You "can".  But why?  To look foolish or pretentious?  If you want something longer than "i.e." you may use "that is".

Comment: Well, you just used "in lieu" in non-academic writing, so yeah I can see you using you "id est" in academic writing. The real question is, *why*. If you want to write in Latin, just write in Latin. It's a thing.

Comment: If you're worried people might not think well of your writing abilities, concentrate on learning the basics, such as *...instead of **its** abbreviated form* first.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was a typo, and one doesn't need to be a genious to guess that. You could either edit it yourself or suggest an edition in a more friendly way instead of ridiculing the inquirer. Anyway, cheers! Rectified it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt "in lieu of" is a commonly used expression. "id est" is not

Comment: @Juya: It wasn't supposed to be an aggressive comment - just a bit of gentle fun. Seriously though - I hadn't realised you weren't a native speaker. You should probably think about using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than ELU.

Comment: "id est" is _almost_ as grating as "exempli gratia" would be.

Comment: Similarly, avoid "e.g.", "etc." "et al.", "inter alia" and all other latinisms; all of them are more clear when written in English: "for example", "and so on", "and all others", "amongst others".  "Vice versa" is still acceptable I suppose.

Comment: @EricLippert: Don't forget that the question is about "academic, formal contexts". Academic audiences are in general much more used to latinisms, and find them much more acceptable than general audiences. This is simply an effect of frequency and familiarity.

Comment: No. I've seen lots of academic writing.  Never seen *id est*.

Comment: @EricLippert That is, quite simply, terrible advice. The abbreviations _i.e._, _e.g._, and _etc._ are all perfectly natural and normal parts of English – a lot of people likely don’t even realise that they’re Latinate. They’re all used by native English speakers in natural, non-academic spoken language, and using unabbreviated English phrases in their stead is often not an improvement. _Et al._ **cannot** be substituted for ‘and all others’ in its commonest usage (multiple authors in bibliographies). Avoiding Latinisms is not and should not be a goal in itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Id est* is not commonly used in academic writing today. Two reasons come to mind.

**The usage is at best uncommon**: A basic [JSTOR search](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=%22id%20est%22) will churn up articles dealing with Latin sources, where *id est* occurs in larger samples of Latin text. Even when I limit the search to 2000 and later, the top sources are all Latin-facing, with titles like:

> "Alabastrum, id est, corpus hominis": Alabaster in the Low Countries, a cultural history

The sources are Latin-centric even if we sort the results by "newest," which gives plenty of results working on the *Aeneid* and other Latin texts. (Sorting by "Relevance" privileges mentions of "id est" in the title, even if the search is full text.) Even if we could find an "id est" usage in English text in one of the 21,659 results as of this search, it would pale in comparison to the 1,684,336 results for "i.e."

**Academic style guides discourage *id est***: Style guides either don't recognize the use of *id est* or make recommendations that preclude its use.

*APA* 6th Ed.:

> *4.26 Latin Abbreviations*: Use the following standard Latin abbreviations only in parenthetical material; in non-parenthetical material, use the English translation of the Latin terms; in both cases, include the correct punctuation that accompanies the term.

Subsequently, i.e. is only listed with the translation "that is," rather than "id est."

*MLA* 8th Ed.:

> *1.6.2 Common Academic Abbreviations*: The following abbreviations are recommended for use in the works-cited list and in in-text citations. Where confusion may result, spell out the words instead.

Subsequently, i.e. is listed as "that is (from the Latin *id est*; set off by commas, unless preceded by a different punctuation mark)."

Both style guides treat "i.e." as an abbreviation that has gone beyond its Latin form. Most academic readers don't learn Latin today, so *id est* would be less familiar than the abbreviation. So the typical academic writing strategy is to use *i.e.* in parentheses, notes, or citations, and to use an English translation in main text.

Comment: Many thanks! A comprehensive answer! Do you think that using it in tests such as the IELTS, GRE, and CPE is unacceptable?

Comment: @Juya You'll most likely confuse your examiner and get marked down... or get marked down - legitimately - for something which _might_ be considered technically correct by someone somewhere but is completely unidiomatic. Worst case, you'll irritate them with your showing off. Don't do it: knowing that _i.e._ is _id est_ is just trivia and has no practical use in English.

Comment: @Juya - Just *never* do it. File it away as a fun fact and amaze your friends with it, but never write it.

Comment: @Juya What they said. It's not that it's unacceptable, as there's no hard rule against it, but it's rhetorically risky and unnecessary, and therefore you shouldn't do it.

Comment: The Oxford university "internal" style guide even eliminates the dots for this and many other abbreviations, ie it gives the abbreviation as just ie not i.e. But in general, American English orthography is more conservative than British English about such things.

Comment: As an anecdote, I know one well-educated person (born in the USA, lived almost his whole life in Japan, works in the computer industry) who invariably uses "id est" in any formal or informal writing. I have no idea why, but presumably he was taught that it was "correct" at some point in his life.

Comment: @Juya And by the same token, also only use "e.g." and not "exempli gratia".

Comment: I use normally use neither *i.e.* nor *that is*. Instead, I use *in other words*. (But the main point is that I use some kind of English phrase.) This is true of all of the normal Latin abbreviations. I'll even use *and so on* (if I use anything at all) rather than *etc.*

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not use it. *i.e.* may have a Latin origin, but its current usage is determined by how English writers use it; it is now an English construction in its own right. *id est* is not used by English writers, and so would be as out of place in normal English writing as any other phrase from another language.